# Extracting string from text

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, programming-languages

I have a string

```
My name is bob.I am fine
```

I want to put each word and the '.' in a vector of strings
How to do this using getline in c++?

**Edit:**

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string word;
while (cin>> word) {
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

I want '.' as a different string which I am unable to do.

Comment: Looks  like a homework question. Kindly look  at [\[what \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes a good question here

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. See [ask] for a list of what's on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but this should work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter)
{
    vector<string> internal;
    stringstream ss(str); 
    string tok;

    while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter))
    {
        internal.push_back(tok);
    }

    return internal;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    string str = "My name is bob.I am fine";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '.')
        {
            str.insert(i++," ");
            str.insert(++i," ");
        }
    }
    vector<string> sep = split(str, ' ');


    for(string t : sep)
        cout << t << endl;
}
```